Oscillatory integral and Riemann integral
Consider the summation, with parameter $a \ge 0$ and non-negative integer $M = 1, 2, 3...$
$$S (a, M) = \sum_{m=1}^M \frac{2}{1+M} \sin\left( \frac{\pi m}{M+1}\right) \sin\left( \frac{\pi m M}{M+1}  \right) \mathrm{e}^{-2 i a \cos \left( \frac{\pi m}{M+1} \right)} $$
Riemann integral appropriate for $M \gg 1$ is
$$I (a, M) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin \left( x \right) \sin \left( M x \right) \mathrm{e}^{- 2 i a \cos \left( x \right)} \mathrm{d}x $$
and should agree with the sum for case $M \gg 1$.
But inputting into Mathematica with $M = 100$ find a disagreement by roughly a factor of $2$.
In plot as function of $a$, $S(a, M)$ (red line) and $I(a, M)$ (blue line):

Here is the Mathematica code:
y1 = Sum[2/(M + 1)*Sin[(Pi*m)/(M + 1)]*Sin[(Pi*m*M)/(M + 1)]*Exp[-2*I*a*Cos[(Pi*m)/(M + 1)]], {m, 1, M}];
p1 = Plot[{Abs[y1]}, {a, 0.1, 100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
y2 = NIntegrate[(2/Pi)*Sin[x]*Sin[M*x]*Exp[-2*I*a*Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi}]
t1 = Table[{a, Abs[y2]}, {a, 1, 100, 0.5}];
p2 = ListLinePlot[t1]
Show[p1, p2]

Why does the integral approximation work up to a factor of $2$?

You could use $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi m M }{M+1} \right)=  -(-1)^m \sin\left(\frac{ m \pi}{M+1} \right)$$

For a given continuous function $f(x)$, the integral
$\int_0^b f(x)\; dx$ is well approximated by Riemann sums
$\frac{b}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M f(b/M)$.  But you have $M$ inside
the integral as well, so all bets are off.  Why not take a
more extreme case?
$$ \int_0^\pi \sin^2(Mx)\; dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
but the "Riemann sum"
$$ \frac{\pi}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M \sin^2(M\pi/M) = 0$$

Thanks! How best to approximate the original sum $S(a, M)$ for large $M$?
